# Git "Pull" from within RStudio

Tags: r, git, rstudio

I am setting up an R project in RStudio (server version, if it makes a difference). I cloned the whole project from my Github account using `git clone`.

#### Problem:

Now I would now like to add a script that will do a Git `pull` command every time the user runs it in Rstudio.
The idea being that the user always have the most recent versions of all files in their project.

#### Goal

This seems easy enough to do using the graphical user interface (Click *Git*, *pull branches*) but I could not figure out how to do it in written code, something like

```
github_pull(branch)
```

I.e. it should replicate the `git pull` command I run in the terminal, but within the R script. Thus avoiding switching to the terminal. Is this possible?

The [devtools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/index.html) package has a command of that name but it seems to be doing something different. I could not find anything on here or in the RStudio help either -- any pointers are much appreciated!

#### Solution

Based on @Mir Henglin 's spot-on solution below, here is what worked for me:

```
system("git pull")
```

However, this only worked if I initially cloned my repository using the *ssh* link (rather than *https*), as described [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200694007-rpostback-askpass)

Comment: Rstudio help was enhanced by a forum in the last week; you might want to try there: https://community.rstudio.com/ Also see their announcement: https://blog.rstudio.com/2017/09/14/rstudio-community/

Comment: @Frank thanks, that's good to know! I also see there are votes toward closing the question as "too broad"; I tried to ask for one specific task / command and how to make it work. I'd be happy to take feedback if I went about it wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `?system` and `?shell`. These functions allow one to run shell commands from within R. I imagine you could call `git pull` pretty easily using those.

EDIT: Here is an example:

`system('pwd')`

`/Users/mirhenglin/projects/R/`

And

`system('git pull --help')`

Comment: This is just wrong on so many ways.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Well then how do you do it in all the right ways?